# Trigger function - PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, plpgsql, sequence

The idea:

1 - The customer can add any value into users.code column
2 - If the customer does not insert data into it, the trigger/funciton has to do the job

- I am able to do that, using this SQL:

> ```
>    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tf_users_update_code_column()
>       RETURNS trigger AS $$
>
>           BEGIN
>
>             IF NEW.company_id = 1 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c1_users_code_seq');
>
>             ELSEIF NEW.company_id = 2 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c2_users_code_seq');
>
>             ELSEIF NEW.company_id = 3 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c3_users_code_seq');
>
>             ELSEIF NEW.company_id = 4 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c4_users_code_seq');
>
>             ELSEIF NEW.company_id = 5 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c5_users_code_seq');
>
>             ELSEIF NEW.company_id = 6 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c6_users_code_seq');
>
>             ELSEIF NEW.company_id = 7 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c7_users_code_seq');
>
>             ELSEIF NEW.company_id = 8 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c8_users_code_seq');
>
>             ELSEIF NEW.company_id = 9 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c9_users_code_seq');
>
>             ELSEIF NEW.company_id = 10 AND NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>             NEW.code = NEXTVAL('c10_users_code_seq');
>
>           END IF;
>
>           return NEW;
>
>           END
>
>     $$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
>
>     2 - Creating the sequences....
>
>     CREATE SEQUENCE c1_users_code_seq  
>     INCREMENT 1  
>     MINVALUE 1
>     MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807  
>     START 1000;
>     CACHE 1;
>
>     CREATE SEQUENCE c2_users_code_seq  
>     INCREMENT 1  
>     MINVALUE 1
>     MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807  
>     START 1000;
>     CACHE 1;
>
>     CREATE SEQUENCE c3_users_code_seq  
>     INCREMENT 1  
>     MINVALUE 1
>     MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807  
>     START 1000;
>     CACHE 1;
>
>     CREATE SEQUENCE c4_users_code_seq  
>     INCREMENT 1  
>     MINVALUE 1
>     MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807  
>     START 1000;
>     CACHE 1;
>
>
>     ... [etc] ...
>
>     3 - Creating the TRIGGER
>
>     CREATE TRIGGER t_users_update_code_column
>       BEFORE INSERT
>       ON users
>       FOR EACH ROW
>       EXECUTE PROCEDURE tf_users_update_code_column();
> ```

- **But because there will be thousands of companies, I can't have thousands of sequences**
- That's why I'm writing the code below:

> ```
>  CREATE TABLE public.company_seqs
>     (company_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
>     last_seq BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>     CONSTRAINT company_seqs_pk PRIMARY KEY (company_id)
>     );
>
>     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION users_code_seq() RETURNS trigger AS $$
>
>     DECLARE
>     last_seq BIGINT;
>     company_id BIGINT;
>     code character varying;
>
>     BEGIN
>             IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
>                     UPDATE public.company_seqs SET last_seq = (last_seq + 1) WHERE company_id = NEW.company_id;
>
>                     ELSEIF NEW.code IS NULL THEN
>                     SELECT last_seq INTO NEW.code FROM public.company_seqs WHERE company_id = NEW.company_id;
>
>             END IF;
>
>             RETURN new;
>
>             END;
>
>     $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
>
>     CREATE TRIGGER tf_users_code_seq
>        BEFORE INSERT
>        ON public.users
>        FOR EACH ROW
>        EXECUTE PROCEDURE users_code_seq();
> ```

When inserting data into the public.users table:

```
INSERT INTO public.users (id,email,encrypted_password,sign_in_count,created_at,updated_at,code,company_id) VALUES (671,'test1@test.com','bucefalo','0','2016-05-03 00:01:01','2016-05-03 00:01:01','default','1');
INSERT INTO public.users (id,email,encrypted_password,sign_in_count,created_at,updated_at,code,company_id) VALUES (672,'test2@test.com','bucefalo','0','2016-05-03 00:01:01','2016-05-03 00:01:01',default,'1');
INSERT INTO public.users (id,email,encrypted_password,sign_in_count,created_at,updated_at,code,company_id) VALUES (673,'test3@test.com','bucefalo','0','2016-05-03 00:01:01','2016-05-03 00:01:01',default,'1');
INSERT INTO public.users (id,email,encrypted_password,sign_in_count,created_at,updated_at,code,company_id) VALUES (674,'test4@test.com','bucefalo','0','2016-05-03 00:01:01','2016-05-03 00:01:01','something','1');
```

I got the following error:

> ```
> BEGIN
> psql:1.sql:3: ERROR:  column reference "last_seq" is ambiguous
> LINE 1: UPDATE public.company_seqs SET last_seq = (last_seq + 1) WHE...
>                                                    ^
> DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
> QUERY:  UPDATE public.company_seqs SET last_seq = (last_seq + 1) WHERE company_id = NEW.company_id
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function users_code_seq() line 10 at SQL statement
> ```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: If the column can't be null, then why don't you just define it as `NOT NULL` and a default value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I've updated the question with my findings and tests - I think it's more clear now. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final code: (It works)

```
ALTER TABLE public.companies ADD COLUMN client_code_increment integer;
ALTER TABLE public.companies ALTER COLUMN client_code_increment SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE public.companies ALTER COLUMN client_code_increment SET DEFAULT 1000;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;


BEGIN;
-- Creating the function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION users_code_seq()
   RETURNS "trigger" AS $$

DECLARE code character varying;

BEGIN

-- if it's an insert, then we update the client_code_increment column value to +1
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        UPDATE public.companies SET client_code_increment = (client_code_increment + 1) WHERE id = NEW.company_id;

        END IF;
-- IF the customer didn't provide a code value, we insert the next available from companies.client_code_increment
        IF NEW.code IS NULL THEN
        SELECT client_code_increment INTO NEW.code FROM public.companies as c WHERE c.id = NEW.company_id ORDER BY client_code_increment DESC;

        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Creating the trigger
CREATE TRIGGER tf_users_code_seq
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON public.users
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE users_code_seq();


COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```